# iSCSI initiator cannot remove session on boot drive

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, configuration, storage-area-network, iscsi, mpio

I'm very new to iSCSI so forgive me if I use the wrong terminology.

I have two nics on my host with IP addresses that can see my iSCSI device (DELL MD3200 if it matters).

We are booting the system off the SAN itself using the broadcom NIC's iSCSI initiator.

I was trying to set up the multipath IO in the Microsoft iSCSI initiator software but I made a mistake and added a copy of the same connection.

So I have multipath working, but I have two paths which are the same nic to same controller (3 sessions in total).

I would like to remove the session (by clicking on the target, selecting the session and click disconnect.  However as this is part of the MPIO for the c:\ I receive the error: The session cannot be logged out since a device on that session is currently being used.

As this is the c:\ for the server I cannot disconnect the target.  I have tried rebooting and windows recreated the duplicate session.

Is there any way to remove the session before the system boots or do you know some other way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using iSCSI boot, the NIC should have some type of configuration menu available at system startup that can be accessed via a key combination.  You would need to modify your connections via this setup interface, since you can't drop the connection once it's in use.

Comment: Makes sense.  Edit the bootup, change it to use a different path, this will then reset the MPIO connections allowing me to drop them for C:\.

Answer (score 1):

Just for prosperity, in the MD3200 Modular Disk Storage Management:

Open the Array.

Under the window that opens:

Storage Array -> iSCSI -> End Sessions

This allows you to remove any session to the iSCSI controllers.